# Admob GADBannerView, does not show when UINavgiationController is present

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've been trying to integrate adMob banner ads in my app and everything works fine till i add a uinavigationcontroller. the test ads don't show anymore. The only view controllers on the story board are a uiviewcontroller and a navigation view controller.

Based on : https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

```
//ViewController.swift

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

  println("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
  bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
  bannerView.rootViewController = self
  bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
}
```

I am using xCode7 with swift

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
//ViewController.swift

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // GADBannerView will show in top left of the view
    let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeBanner,origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out(convert this to swift),

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview: bannerView];
```

UPDate:(in Swift)

```
self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
bannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(bannerView)
bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

Comment: the image loads on top of the navigationController

Comment: i updated the code for swift
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(bannerView)

Comment: how did you initialize  bannerView?  initialize it with kGADAdSizeBanner

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

Comment: init as follow,      bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];     if above answer helped, give vote.

Comment: bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

Comment: did not work throwing a new error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94938/discussion-between-avaan-and-mugunthan-balakrishnan).